# bug in the output of printing a matrix from the user in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int m,n,a[n][m],b[m][n],i,j;
    printf("in order enter line and column of matrix :");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
          }
      }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%d \n",a[i][j]);
          }
      }
  }
```

In the last line for printing the result, this program has a bug, this program duty is giving several line and column and then give elements from a user at last print the matrix

Comment: You need to allocate the memory for a based on the values m and n.
Activate warning, you will get ‘m’ is used uninitialized in this function and ‘n’ is used uninitialized in this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you will use a variable size for the matrices, the arrays have to declared after their size is known.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int m,n,i,j;
    printf("in order enter line and column of matrix :");
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);

    int a[n][m],b[m][n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
          }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%d \n",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```